# How to find the position of sys.argv() arguments?

Tags: python, passwords, arguments, position, sys

I'm trying to add command line arguments to my python script using the `sys.argv()` list, I have got the basics down, but I'm really doing y head in trying to figure out how some of the things work. First of all, what I'm building is a password cracking / hashing tool. And secondly, my main current problem right now is looking for the position of arguments.

```
'''
_____________________________________________________________
        |
  -dict   / -d  |  Initiate a dictionary attack on an any kind of hash
  -hash   / -H  |  Hashes a password into an any kind of hash
        |
  All hashtypes supported:
  MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA384, SHA256, SHA512
-------------------------------------------------------------
'''
-hT = hashType
```

For example: `python3 main.py -d -hT md5`

What I want to do is find the position of where, `-hT` or any other arguments are and I can get the position as a value. Currently the method I was trying... which by the way is so scuffed, it got to the point of where it was legit causing scoping issues.

```py
if '-pH' in args:
    if '-ph' in args[2]:
        password_hi = args[3]
        print(password_hi)
    elif '-ph' in args[4]:
        password_hi = args[5]
...
```

Turns out, that isn't a very efficient way of doing things. I would like to know if someone can explain how I can get the argument position of a specific argument (e.g. `"-pH"`).

Comment: Have you taken a look at argparse? Its much better suited for making CLI tools like this compared to manually parsing sys.argv.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into it :)

Comment: Also it can generate a help/usage printout for you dynamically, which is kind of amazing.  You then bind it to `-h` or as you see fit.

Comment: BTW, `sys.argv` is a list, not a function—you don't call it.